# svn --non-interactive checkout REPO DIR fails on mac os 10.5.8

Tags: svn

I'm running Subversion 1.6.13 on Mac OS 10.5.8, and I need to be able to checkout a repo using the --non-interactive option.

The following command works fine:

```
$ svn --force checkout https://MY_REPO MY_DIR
```

I'm not prompted for a username or password since I have already entered it once before. The following command fails, however:

```
$ svn --force --non-interactive checkout https://MY_REPO MY_DIR
```

Here is the error that I receive:

> svn: OPTIONS of 'MY_REPO': authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge

Any ideas?

Comment: what happens when you run the command without --non-interactive option ? did you answer yes the last time when it prompted for storing password in plain text ?

Comment: I did answer yes when it asked me about storing passwords in plain text. When I run the command "svn checkout MY_REPO MY_DIR", the checkout happens as normal with no username/password prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, I think. It's a bug with subversion on Mac OS X Leopard. Here is a link to a subversion bug report: http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=3059

The version of subversion is different in the bug report, but I'm guessing that the problem remains...